# what's wrong with this sql statement?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

in access i am doing this:

```
insert into accounts_changes 
 (select * 
  from accounts 
  where [Agency Code] 
  in (select * from tableimport))
```

it says that it doesnt like this INSERT statement

update:

```
sSql = "insert into accounts_changes (select * from Accounts where [Agency Code] in (select [Agency Code] from tableimport))"
```

i did what mark said and it is still giving me the same error message

```
syntax error in INSERT INTO statement
```

when i do this:

```
ssql = "select [Agency Code] from tableimport"
CurrentDb.Execute ssql
```

it says CANNOT EXECUTE SELECT QUERY

Comment: I really hate those kind of error messages.  You know, when the compiler says "Error: I don't like this insert statement."

Comment: EXECUTE is for DML statements, not for SELECT statements. If you want to see what it returns, try CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(strSQL).RecordCount. Or for heaven's sake, just paste it into SQL view in a new blank query and run it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part may have misled you:

```
ssql = "select [AgencyCode] from tableimport"
CurrentDb.Execute ssql
```

*Execute* requires an "action" query (INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, or SELECT INTO).  When you give *Execute* a plain (row returning) SELECT query, you will always get error #3065, "Cannot execute a select query".  It doesn't mean there was anything wrong with your SELECT statement.  Test your SELECT statement by pasting it into SQL View of a new query.

You showed two variations of [AgencyCode] ... one with and another without a space between Agency and Code.  Which is it?

I think your original INSERT statement had an extra pair of parentheses which aren't needed.  Try it this way:

```
insert into accounts_changes
select * 
from Accounts
where [Agency Code] in (
    select [Agency Code] from tableimport)
```

If that still fails, verify you have the same number of fields, with the same field names and data types in both Accounts and accounts_changes.  If the fields in the two tables don't match exactly, list the fields explicitly as @pcent showed you.

Comment: While Access uses the term "action query," for general SQL terminology, these are DML statements.

Comment: Access calling DML statements "action queries" used to make me cringe.  Seems like a query should only be a row-returning SELECT statement. I finally gave in to make it easier to communicate with normal Access users.

Comment: I understand, but you get ridiculed on SO for using Access-specific terminology to answer Access questions if it violates the rigid rules of those who never use Access. It's also good to not be provincial when it comes to terminology -- my comment was never intended as a criticism of your post, just a tangential comment/reminder.

Answer (score 14):

This is wrong:

```
select *
from accounts
where [Agency Code] in (select * from tableimport)
```

You can only select one column in the subquery for an IN clause. You want something like this:

```
select *
from accounts
where [Agency Code] in (select [Agency Code] from tableimport)
```

You need to check the exact name of the column in the table `tableimport`. The above is just my best guess.

Comment: mark sorry this does not work unfortunately, im getting the same error statmeent

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to select the agency code from tableimport instead of *.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the column you'd like to search on `tableimport` inner select.

Also, you could declare the fields of the table being inserted and the fields returned:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_EXAMPLE (A, B) SELECT AA, BB FROM TABLE_ORIGIN
```

Comment: Yes that is the best practice and do anything else is to risk your data integrity if columns change. 

Additionally you probaly don't want the () around the select statement. I know in SQL server that would not work.

Answer (score -2):

this worked:

```
insert into accounts_changes select * from Accounts where [Agency Code] in (select [Agency Code] from tableimport)
```

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked your own answer.  I'll leave mine up so you can look at the part about Execute with a SELECT query.

Comment: Why use an IN clause instead of a plain old INNER JOIN?